# User cannot sign in for the second time (using Devise and Omniauth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am using Omniauth and Devise. Users using gmail or FB can easily create an account and sign-in and sign-out. When a user signs up with my service (using Devise) as the authentication service the user can sign in once after they  create an account (or reset their password). Now after doing sign out and when they try to sign in again, they get an invalid password error.

Any ideas?

I think it used to work before..... something happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the logic for logging in with Facebook you need to check if the email address already exists in the database, and if it does simply log them in instead of creating a new account.

For more info check out the [Omniauth Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview).

Comment: this happens when a user creates an account and sign in using DEvice native use/password capability not when the user logs on with FB or Gmail